# How to work with multiple ssh keys

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

GitHub Users,

I am newbie on github and have some issue with git setup.
I have 2 account with different users on github and i have setup git on my system 2 times

> First **/.ssh** folder (as usual) (contain id_rsa which copied in first
>   account)
>  Second **/.ssh/new** folder  (contain id_rsa which copied in
>   second account)

now at the time of push how can i switch between ssh key?

Because if i would like to push for second account it will use .ssh key instead of .ssh/new and gives me error.

Please make me correct if i am understood something wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why would you want to place "second" keys in `~/.ssh` sub-folder? Why not to stick to convention of having key suffixed by numbers, like: `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.1`, `id_rsa.2`, etc...

Comment: @JuicyScripter Just want to make separation , you are also right however i need to tell git which key need to use and how?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(I've voted to close this as a possible duplicate, but I might as well add a similar answer anyway.)

When using the SSH transport, GitHub identifies you as a user based on the SSH key that you use to authenticate.  So, you need to make sure that git is using one SSH key for one repository and another for the other.

I'm going to assume that:

1. You have a GitHub account called `user1`, and you've added to that account the public key corresponding to your local private key `/home/whoever/.ssh/id_rsa`.  Let's say that the repository you're interested in accessing as `user1` is `user1/whatever` on GitHub.
2. You have a second GitHub account called `user2` and you've added to that account the public key corresponding to your local private key `/home/whoever/.ssh/new/id_rsa`.  Let's say that the repository you're interested in accessing as `user2` is `user2/whatever` on GitHub.

The simplest way to do deal with this is to create a new "remote" (i.e. a nickname for a remote repository) for each repository, where the hostname is in each remote's URL is actually an alias that you've set up in `~/.ssh/config`.  (If that config file doesn't exist, you'll have to create it.)

For example, one entry in the `~/.ssh/config` file might look like:

```
Host github-as-user1
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then you can add a remote called `gh-user1`, say, with:

```
git remote add gh-user1 git@github-as-user1:user1/whatever.git
```

... and then if you want to push your `master` branch to the repository `user1/whatever` on GitHub using the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key, you can just do:

```
git push gh-user1 master
```

In order to push as the other user (`user2`) to the second repository, you need to add a second alias to you `~/.ssh/config` file.  For example:

```
Host gh-as-user2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/new/id_rsa
```

Then to push to that second repository as the different user, you can just do:

```
git push gh-user2 master
```

Comment: So git will not work with out .ssh/config?  Why can't git take a parameter like standard ssh?  -i .ssh/my_github_key

Comment: I would add that this can be tested through `ssh -T git@gh-as-user1` and `ssh -T git@gh-as-user1`.
If it does not work, try to run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/new/id_rsa` or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: If the keys you're using exist outside of the ~/.ssh directory, they won't work unless you do: `ssh-add /path/to/key`