# Using multiple ssh keys for same host, without using an alias

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have two bitbucket accounts and ssh keys to match. I've seen [many](http://cocoapods.org/) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config) to [manage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924210/how-to-work-with-multiple-ssh-keys) using multiple keys on the same host through aliasing, but unfortunately, I need my git references to be common.

The reason I need them to be common is because I'm working on shared projects with [Pods](http://cocoapods.org/). This means that the remote git source url needs to be the same for all developers working on the projects, but I can't guarantee that everyone will be able to setup the same alias as me and they shouldn't be expected to.

I've tried the foolish attempt at specifying my user accounts like so:

```
Host BitbucketA
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 User UserA

Host BitbucketB
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_userB
 User UserB
```

Thinking that I could specify to use id_rsa_userB whenever I'm trying to access one of UserB's repositories. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be how it works.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2):

You are really close to a solution, that is essentially what I have done and it does work. See my answer and the link below.

Here is how I setup my ssh keys for two accounts on the same server on my Mac:

This is only necessary if you have logins to two separate accounts on the same Git remote repo.

Create two SSH keys:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa_account1
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa_account2
```

Add this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host git_account1
        User git
        HostName git.xxxx.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_account1
Host git_account2
        User git
        HostName git.xxxx.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_account2
```

SSH translates the `Host` name into the `HostName` prepending the `User` and selects the `IdentityFile`. This allows two or more repos for the same URL with different ssl certs.

Also see Nerderati: [~/.ssh/config & git](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Comment: But the OP specifically stated that they don't want to use aliases because then everyone on the team must have the same setup on their boxes, that is, to use `git_account1` in the repo URIs.

Comment: So you disagree with the last sentence: "ssh translates the "Host" name into the "HostName" prepending the "User" and selects the ssh "IdentityFile". The allows two or more repos for the same URL with different ssl certs." Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I certainly agree with it.  But as I read the original question, the whole point of it is to ask how not have *different hosts* (aliased or not) in the URIs because that would require everyone on the team have the same SSH setup.  The problem with my answer is that it requires setting up developers' boxes as well.  I think this problem does not have any pretty solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Gist about this:
https://gist.github.com/yinzara/bbedc35798df0495a4fdd27857bca2c1

You can manage multiple keys for the same host using directories.

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to using a pair of shell scripts, and an environment variable:

```
$ cat >~/bin/ssh-acct-one
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_account1 $@
^D
$ chmod +x $_
$ GIT_SSH=ssh-acct-one git clone ssh://git@git.xxxx.com/...
```

…and the same for the second identity file.  (The call on the last line assumes you have `~/bin` on your `$PATH`).

The reason for this clumsiness is that Git passes `$GIT_SSH` directly to `exec()` and not to `/bin/sh -c` or the like, so no ususal shell expansions are performed.

When debugging, you can also use `GIT_TRACE=1` to make Git show you what is being executed and modify your scripts passng `-vvv` to `ssh` to make that report what's being done (including what key (identity file) it's using).